# Using "will" and "won't" for habits

Tags: modal-verbs, habitual-aspect

According to a grammar book (Advanced Grammar in Use,3rd Edition) we can use "will" in order to describe a particular habit in the present. e.g. Everyday he will wake up at 7 am and eat his breakfast.
Is this the case for the negative form of "will"? Or is "won't" used to express annoyance,  criticize a behavior and not to describe a habit? 
Is "won't" used in a correct way in the following sentences?
 "Every time I ask him how he's doing, he won't answer me"
"Every time he drinks coffee, he won't have sugar with it."

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: You can use ***won't answer***, or in fact ***doesn't answer*** - which is generally less emphatic in its meaning (less strong negativity).

Comment: But, can we use "would" in the same context,in order to talk about the present? e.g. "He would go to church every Sunday morning."

Comment: In some contexts that is fine, but not to talk about the present (and continuous habits) - it is a past and ceased habit / pattern / ritual. One exception (and there may be others) would be when a person is confirming a current habit, so if someone asks: "Is he very religious?", you could answer with: "He would go to church every Sunday morning.".

Comment: @V.Lydia By analogy with "mustn't" and "must not," I would suspect there's also kind of a distinction between using either "won't" or "will not" to describe a habit...

Comment: @M, Lydia Actually, "won't" sounds more emphatic than "will not." "he won't answer me" is just about the same as saying "he refuses/will [habitually] refuse to answer me."

Comment: So, "won't" is not correct in the sentence "Every time he drinks coffee, he won't have sugar with it." ?

Comment: @Elian Whether the contraction is more forceful might come down to the customs of local usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the case for the negative form of "will"?

[*Will*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) and [*won't*](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs.html) are [modal verbs](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/modal-verb), which the Oxford Dictionaries link defines as expressing necessity or probability. In the context of habits, it means they express what the person habitually does (*will*) or habitually avoids (*won't*). As such, if *will* is used to express a habit, then *won't* can be used with the same sentence construction to express the opposite habit.

> Or is "won't" used to express annoyance, criticize a behavior and not to describe a habit? Is "won't" used in a correct way in the following sentences?

It could do so. Depending on the example, it could also simply describe a habit without any emotional content, or it could express annoyance at a habit. Arguably, your first negative example falls into this category. The sentence doesn't necessarily imply that *not answering* is habitual, but it also doesn't necessarily imply it isn't. Likewise, one could read emotion into the sentence, or depending on the broader context, it could simply be a statement of fact. In any case, the grammar of the sentence is correct.

Your last example does sound like a statement of habit, though "he won't" arguably expresses more a habit of choice / volition than a habit of action, which might be better expressed using "he doesn't". Again, your sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct to say "I won't be going back to the store because of poor customer service.", but you could also say, "I won't be having any more automobile problems thanks to my great mechanic!", so it's more of a descriptor of "will not" in both contexts, not just annoyance or criticisms.